# Blazor How to emit an event using the onClick event

Tags: blazor

I have 2 pages that have the following and both pages in their code behind have their own Search Method.

```
<button class="btn input-search-btn no-outline" @onclick="@(async () => await Search())">
```

so What I want to do is place this in it's own component and when the user clicks the button that the component raises a 'search' event and then each page using this component to implements it's own search. (there is more to the component, but this is my basic issue)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

SearchComponent.razor

```
<button class="btn input-search-btn no-outline" @onclick="@RequestSearch">

@code
{
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback OnSearchRequested {get;set;}

    async Task RequestSearch()
    {
      await OnSearchRequested.InvokeAsync();
    }
}
```

PageA.razor

```
<SearchComponent @OnSearchRequested="SearchA" />

@code
{
   async Task SearchA()
   {
      // Page A search logic

   }

}
```

PageB.razor

```
<SearchComponent @OnSearchRequested="SearchB" />

@code
{
   async Task SearchB()
   {
      // Page B search logic

   }

}
```

Note that you can bind search parameters (string, options etc say `SearchParams`) in `SearchComponent` and raise `EventCallback<SearchParams>` instead.